# Transparent background in Android webview running WebGl

Tags: android, webview, three.js, android-webview, webgl

I was successful having a tranparent webview background with the following:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
myWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

But, it appears that

```
myWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Kills the WebGl renderer I run using three.js.

Is there a solution for transparent webview + WebGl at the same time on Android?

Comment: Did you find out yet? I'm currently trying out the same thing, but I can imagine OpenGL doesn't like this.

Comment: It seems to be the case - i.e. did not find a solution